# Spray on Lacquer for Vertical Surface

Tags: finishing, staining, polyurethane

I have a rectangular speaker cabinet (basically a box).  Can I use spray lacquer and spray all sides at once?  Otherwise I have to account for a lot of overspray.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you mean by "all at once"? You can't spray from more than one direction, so you can't literally do the top and all four sides "at once" as that would require spraying from at least two directions simultaneously. If you mean can you spray them in a single sitting then most definitely yes, that's the normal way you'd spray anything like this — by walking around it as you spray or by having the piece mounted on a turntable/lazy Susan and turning it during spraying.

Comment: I mean spray one side (face), rotate, next side, rotate, next side (rear), rotate, next side, then top, coat complete

Comment: Like a lazy Susan except I walk around it

Comment: Yes you can spray that way, although it's more efficient to spray with a corner towards you so you're spraying two adjacent faces with each pass (I believe this is the normal way a pro would do it). Re. a lazy Susan type arrangement, if you'd find it useful to have one of those in the shop to help with spraying you can build one in about 10 minutes from scraps + one nail as the pivot! A friend of mine came up with the design a few months back because he couldn't wait for a lazy Susan mechanism to be delivered and it works ridiculously well for something that's so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You'll want something to rest one side on while it's drying.  You can buy those triangle things like these:
https://www.woodcraft.com/products/painters-pyramid-10-pack-new-improved?via=573621f469702d06760016d0%2C5764236869702d3baa0025aa
or you could use some scrap plywood squares are drive a screw all the way through it.  This way you you can finish the whole thing and let it dry without resting a side fully one a surface.

Comment: So i can spray all 5 Side’s at once?  Top, face, rear, sides x2

Comment: I have “feet” on the box

Comment: Yes.  I'd take the feet off it they aren't the adhesive type though.then you could spray all 6 sides.