# Moisture Blushing or Inadequately Mixed Satin Wipe-On Poly?

Tags: finishing, polyurethane, refinishing

In the final step of finishing my speakers I was putting satin wipe-on poly over my danish oil.  The danish oil sat for 6 days on my walnut paperbacked veneer in my basement with a dehumidifier going.  It was approx 70F degrees and 40 humidity.  I forgot to shake on my second coat of poly and then added a shaken third.

I'm wondering if this is blushing or moisture.  If it's blushing I can get a 'deblusher' but I need to order it and wait.  If it's the cloudy poly then I need to likely strip and re-coat.  If it's cloudy poly is there any way I can avoid that in the future?  Perhaps put a gloss down for the first 2 then a final of satin (super well shaken).

To remove the coat should I just use an orbital with 220 grit (it's on paper backed veneer)

[image: Blushing or Satin]
[image: Blushing or Satin]

Comment: Impossible to be certain here but I doubt humidity is the issue as many people varnish in conditions much much more humid than where you are (it regularly tops 80% here, and most guys aren't running dehumidifiers). And unfortunately any time you don't shake or thoroughly stir a varnish that isn't gloss you can be certain that the matting agents were not evenly distributed, so it's all too easy to get a little more here and a little less there. This should have been clearly evident after that coat, the lighter areas would have been noticeably more matt.

Comment: Re. getting the varnish off, I don't know how thick or thin your veneer is but many modern veneers are very thin and it's extremely difficult to sand off finish from them with complete success, sand-throughs along edges and especially in corners are all too easy. I always recommend stripping over sanding anyway to remove finishing, it's nearly always preferable, but the paper-backed veneer complicates things. I don't know how it responds (have zero experience and have never read up on it).

Comment: I sanded and refinished and it got rid of most of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sanded and refinished and it got rid of most of it.