# How long until setting Waterlox sealer vertical

Tags: finishing, staining

I am building a speaker box (cube) and finishing 5 sides.  Normally I lay the box flat and do one side then rotate and do another side.  Waterlox requires 24 hours between coats.  Does that mean it’s 24 hours laying flat before I rotate it such that the side would be perpendicular with the ground?  Or could I wait 4 hours and then rotate and do another side.

Comment: Finish is dry when it's dry, and that is dependent on many factors outside of the product used so this is really unanswerable in terms of giving you a number. Didn't we cover this already? This previous Q of yours basically does, https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/7676/polyurethane-a-box-vertical-sides and there are numerous previous Answers here that go into various details about variation in drying times, and how you can use supports for putting freshly finished sides down if needed (e.g. as used when doing both sides of a shelf).

Comment: But you're doing only five sides, you just put it on its base and finish as it stands!

Comment: I’ve never used this finish and the 24 hour drying time before recoat is throwing me for a loop. So what you’ve said implies that I can apply the finish vertically and not worry about it being uneven on the top vs the bottom due to running toward the bottom?

Comment: Cutting to the chase here, doesn't matter that it's Waterlox. Convert it to wiping varnish for best results.

Comment: Called the company and they said it can be applied vertically.  Thank you for taking the time for advice!